# Preferred or common connectors for CAN bus on the PCB?

Tags: connector, can

Looking for a decent connector to carry CAN bus signal from/to a PCB. What is the most common type? Ideally something compact. I would like to avoid DB9 since it looks too much like RS232. This isn't going into a hostile environment.

Comment: To my knowledge, SubD9 is _the_ standard as CAN bus connector. I also once saw RJ45. However, as CAN bus signals aren't special, you can use whatever connector you want.

Comment: http://www.interfacebus.com/Can_Bus_Connector_Pinout.html shows 9 pin D plug as well as some RJ options and some pin header options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commonly-used connector is [M12](http://www.digikey.com/product-highlights/us/en/3m-m12-wiremount-connectors/3210) (IEC 61076-2-101). Example, [CR2033](http://www.ifm.com/products/gb/ds/CR2033.htm) (not to be confused with the battery [CR2032](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CR2032_battery)):

[image: Annotated image of CR2033]

For this device there are both male and female connectors so many devices can be chained using standard cables.

Note that it ought to be M12 with five wires as the standard is to use pin 5 (the center pin) for CAN_L (many sensor cables only use 4 wires):

```
Pin#   Signal
------------------
 1     
 2     Vcc
 3     CAN_GND
 4     CAN_H
 5     CAN_L
```

Alternatively, use a non-standard wiring scheme (with the associated risk).

Comment: M12 connectors suitable for PCB mounting exists. A picture is coming!